# How to review OS-boot-time error that flashes by too fast to be read?

Tags: grub, arch-linux, bootloader

I've just finished installing Arch Linux on a virtual machine and, until now, everything is working, including grub. However, when I boot the OS, an error message relating to grub appears, but it disappears so fast that I am not able to read it.

The bootloader works as intended, but obviously there is something wrong. Is there a way I can check what problems there are?

Answer (score 2):

The error is very likely logged either to one of the system logs (by way of the syslog daemon), to the kernel log (reviewed using `dmesg`), or both.

I would try `dmesg | less` first to review the kernel log (you can use `/` to initiate a search).

If that does not turn up anything, turn to the system logs in `/var/log`. I'm not sure which exact file this would be on Arch, but something along the lines of `grep -rHi grub /var/log/* | less` should get you started.

If neither of these turn up anything useful, with a bit of trickery you may be able to set up a serial console. That is a very different question and quite frankly not likely to be needed, but if you need to, despite its age you may find that the [remote serial console howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/) provides some insights.

Answer (score 2):

dmesg will unlikely show anything related to GRUB.
Though, my best guess is that you are having a missing locale error. Try running:
sudo cp /usr/share/locale/en@quot/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo /boot/grub/locale/en.mo
sudo gunzip /boot/grub/locale/en.mo
sudo cp /boot/grub/locale/en@quot.mo /boot/grub/locale/en_US.mo

Sources: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/29043
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1075065#p1075065

Answer (score 2):

You can pause GRUB by pressing the <kbd>Pause</kbd> (<kbd>Break</kbd>) key on your keyboard. Resume with <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd>.

To pause the output when the error is displayed, press  <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd> followed by <kbd>Pause</kbd> repeatedly until the error is displayed.

Comment: Very helpful. Was a bit hard to get the timing, but after few tries I "freezed" the error message. And the error was... a missing locale just like @Ernestas suggested (`file '/grub/locale/pt.gmo' not found`). Thank you both.